# Most efficient file type to read in only specific rows, in python (very large files)

Tags: python, csv, file, storage, parquet

I am currently using parquet files due to their outstanding read-in time. However now I am looking to change functionality of my program slightly. Files will become too large for the memory and instead I wish to read in only specific rows of the files.

The files have around 15gb of data each (and I will be using multiple files), with several hundred columns, and millions of rows. If I wanted to read in e.g. only row x, operate on that, and then read in a new row (millions of times over), what would be the most efficient file type by which to do this?

I am not too concerned about compression, as it is ram that is my limiting factor, rather than storage.

Thanks in advance for your expertise!

Comment: Not clear if you want to select specific rows from your input files or perform some operations on all rows of a given input files,

Comment: Did you try `.hdf5` files and the `h5py` package?

Comment: The hope is to be able to select a single row at random (for instance), and operate on that row. But without reading through the entire file. I really like hdf5, however I don't believe it is possible to select single rows without reading through. Am i correct?

Comment: You can jump to any position in a file without reading the content. But in order to make it useful you will need to create some index first. Like byte positions of end of line chars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on exact requirements, I'd look at:

- [SQLite](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html)
- [RocksDB](http://rocksdb.org/) (using "row number" as the key).

Note that Rocks DB will produce multiple files in a single directory rather than an individual file.  Last i looked Rocks DB did not support secondary indexes so you are stuck with whatever choice you make for the Key, unless you want to rewrite the data.  The RocksDB project does not have python bindings but there are a few floating around on github.

SQLLite, at least, for the initial load might be pretty slow (I would recommend loading then creating an index on "row number") after the initial load.  But it allows for creating secondary indices and finding multiple rows at a time by those indices reasonably efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you will not get everything right processing your date. If the raw data is stored as CSV, save not just debugging time and convert CSV to parquet using i.e.:

- https://github.com/pola-rs/polars
- https://duckdb.org

**Update 2021.11.09**

For reading an input file row by row you do not need any fancy format, CSV will suffice. You may get an improvement in some situations (slow hard drive/slow NFS) by compressing the CSV with i.e. zstd.

On the other hand my suggestion would be to run away from line by line processing of a biggish data and use data frames. Specifying types of input columns, finding ones with categorical values will permit you to drastically shrink RAM requirements. If the order of the rows is not important you may also sort your inputs which will improve at least compression.

Loading data into a data frame from a parquet will be faster than doing the same from CSV/TSV.
If you will be still bumping into out of memory errors you can  use Linux split to divide the input(s) into a manageable chunks and merge results if needed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I think it misunderstands the question. I am not looking to convert to parquet, I am asking what filetype will allow me to efficiently read in single rows without reading in the entire file.